# How do you organize your RPGLE subversion repository on IBM i?

Tags: svn, ibm-midrange, rpgle

How do you organize your RPGLE subversion repository on IBM i ?

I'm currently working in a travel business company that has a vast amount (about 13k) of RPGLE - sources for their in-house application and finally they want to use version control and adopt a more modern style of coding (the whole WDSC - RDi stuff).

So my all-the-time-project is to sanify and modernize the whole coding process bit by bit.

The [open source subversion for OS/400](http://www.softlanding.com/subversion/d-subversion.htm) works like a charm with just 2 minor issues during install.

I have a pretty good image in my head how it should work, but i think it breaks with some traditions, so i want your opinion.

```
/subversion/repositories/{name of the in-house-application}
   /{project_a}
       /trunk
           /doc
           /sql
           /{a source file that is named like the project. i.e. project_a }
               /myRPGsrc.rpgle
               /myCLLEsrc.clle
               /myDDSsrc.dspf
               /myDDSsrc.pf
               /compile.clle
            .iseries_project_properties
            .project
       /branch
       /tag
   /{project_b}
   /global_stuff
   /nightly_build
```

So the main difference would be not having different source files like QRPGLESRC, QCLSRC, QDDSSRC and the like and instead *one* sourcefile that contains all project sources and can be checked out as an WDSC-project. The project-sourcefile could also easily be named "src" like it is common on other repos, but in case some developers would want to check out multiple projects into /QSYS.LIB/SOMELIB.LIB/ they wouldn't have to worry about namespaces themselves.

So what do you think? is it hybris? do you see problems? Do you have already some experience? please share! :)

Comment: Would you care to share the issues you had with the Subversion install? I want my group to evaluate subversion as a replacement for Turnover now that we're switching to Rational (the Eclipse based editor).

Comment: Sure no prob, they were really minor though :) 
In the V5R4-savf the CMDs were all PRDLIB(SVNTRUNK), CHGCMD that to your RSTLIB.

The 2nd issue was the auth.conf for SVN usage as a Apache_mod.
Make sure the CCSID is right, and that QTMHHTTP is in the SVNGROUP
Srry for the shortnote..300 A is hard ;)

Comment: I would avoid the Subversion for iSeries. The last I knew it wasn't being maintained. You are better off using VisualSVN on a old Windows machine.

Comment: there is an V6R1 version up there, soo there must be maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

How are the source and objects currently organized?  Would you want to set up Subversion to work with the current library structure instead of creating this new IFS directory structure?

I'd suggest using object types (pgm, file, cmd, pnlgrp, sql, etc.) for file extensions instead of source file types (rpgle, clle, sql, etc.).  You could have xyz.rpgle and xyz.clle sources in conflict as they both compile to XYZ *PGM.

Comment: Currently there's 1 src lib and a few obj libs. 
it should work to check out into tmp libs. 
My shop uses a strict obj naming. I recognized the conflict potential, but as all pgmrs are used to naming rules i just modified the existing ones a bit to avoid conflicts by cutting the objname 1A.

thx :)